# Environment variable in app.js file in sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I would like to access environment variable (config/env/development) from inside the app.js file.

How would I go about getting the variables in that file?

I think I can get the variables in for example the view by using sails.config.variableName, but I do not have the sails variable.

What I am doing is adding a
setInterval(function() {
   stuffTODO
}, 60000);

This is at the end of the app.js file.
I would like to be able to put the 60000 into a environment variable that would get read here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config object is available on the Sails app instance (sails). By default, this is exposed on the global scope during lift, and therefore available from anywhere in your app.

source: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Configuration

That means you should be able to access the sails variable within your app.js file!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I am still not able to see how to get it.  I get a undefined when I try to access the variable.  I added a pastbin of the app.js file where I would like to access.  http://pastebin.com/5VkQKhBC

Comment: can you add a link to your config/env/development.js file? Direct children to the config object show up in the config folder like this: config/test.js --> sails.config.test. You declare the test attribute in a file called test.js. The link includes some info on this under the "Standard configuration files (config/*)" section.

Comment: I actually don't think the sails object has everything it needs at this point.  I am able to get to the config variables in the controller and views.  So everything works as I would expect that way.  They just don't appear to be there in the app.js file.